# ジェネリクスのクラスを引数に取るとき、デフォルト引数を取る方法を教えてください。

Tags: typescript

ジェネリクスを `new` するには `{new(): T}` すればよいということを、以下のドキュメントで知りました。

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function

しかし、ジェネリクスのクラスを引数に取るとき、デフォルト引数をとる方法がわかりません。

```js
class Hoge {
  constractor() {}
}

function hoge<T extends Hoge>(
  hogeClass: {new(): T} = Hoge // この = Hoge が typeof Hoge だと思われてしまう
) {}
```

以上が通したいコード例です。ご存知の方はお教えいただけると助かります。

Comment: 単に generics を使う必要が無かったようです。
`hogeClass: {new(): Hoge} = Hoge` で十分でした。